# Multiple session initiation from Java front end to R

Tags: java, r, multiple-instances, rjava

We have front end web page developed using Java. In the back end we are doing some modelling using r. Now Java to R multiple instances initiation is not happening. Only one user can upload his data and do his analysis on that application web page. Is there a solution to get multiple users upload their data files and do analysis simultaneously without able to see other users data.

We are hosting the application using Tom cat, R server is getting initialized from Java.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: you have multiple web sessions in Tomcat but when multiple users simultaneously pass data to the R server then that data is not isolated? If so then I'd guess that's a problem with the implementation of the R server and not the language or language binding itself. I'd suggest you try to fix the R server or, if that is not possible, use multiple instances of the R server and manage a pool of connections in your Tomcat application.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show the code that does not work and the library used in integrating Java and R.